# How to delete a column from a Class?

Tags: parse-platform

On Parse.com there is, in the web interface, a way to delete a column from a Class.

Inside **Core** x **Data** -> **More** -> **Delete column**.

Is there a way to perform the same operation in **Cloud code**?

Answer (score 1):

As far as this thread is concerned, you cannot possibly do that without a hack or two.

https://www.parse.com/questions/is-there-any-way-to-drop-and-add-a-column-in-a-class-table-with-cloud-code

Comment: Yeah. Thanks. I think I had actually read the article you mention, while doing my own research, before writing my post. Bad luck for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can do so with the help of the REST API, but unfortunately not directly via CloudCode... This is not a hack its just functionality that is only available in the REST API. But it may be a slightly more tedious method than you may like...

Rest call from your Cloud Code back to your own backend... You can find how to make a REST call from Cloud Code from http://parseplatform.github.io/docs/cloudcode/guide/#networking
something like this, of course you will need to add your own backends url, params and headers and I'm not sure but you may have to authenticate with Master Key

```
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
  url: 'http://www.example.com/',`enter code here`
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
  }
}).then(function(httpResponse) {
  console.log(httpResponse.text);
}, function(httpResponse) {
  console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
});
```

See this link on "Modifying the Schema":
http://parseplatform.github.io/docs/rest/guide/#modifying-the-schema

from the dashboard request the following parameters are also send in the body of "PUT" request:

```
{
"className": "<CLASSNAME>,
"fields":
        {
        "<FIELDNAM>]":{
                       "__op":"Delete"
                      }
        },
"_method":"PUT",
"_ApplicationId":"<APPLICATIONID>",
"_ClientVersion":"js1.6.14",
"_MasterKey":"<MASTERKEY>",
"_InstallationId":"<INSTALLATIONID>"
}
```

Comment: https://docs.parseplatform.org/rest/guide/#modifying-the-schema